# Form is still submitted even when radio button is not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

***Functionality:***

Users need to submit in a form before being allowed to continue the functionality. The form consists of

Name:

Email:

Have Your Purchase:    [ ]Yes      [ ] No

[Submit]

***Issue:***

I have created the above form, enable the email validation function and have also enable the radio button to be a required field as well. However, this is the functionality at this point:

1.) When user doesn't input any field, a popup text will display:  *please input all field

2.) When User input only name and not email, a popup text will display: * please input a valid email address

3.) In email field, when user doesn't input a correct email, a popup text will display: * please input a valid email address

However, at this point, after user has input both name and email, the page is navigated to the next page when the correct behaviour is that: ***a popup text will display:  *please input all field*** for the user to select the option in the radio button.

I did not set the submit button as an  tag, this is personal preference as i have set a function call `Submit()` to the button, hence, I am trying to find out what has gone wrong when I try to validate all fields.

Hence, what has gone wrong when Itry to validate all fields within the Submit function call method?

Please help.

code:

Comment: where is the validation for the radio fields?

Comment: How does your function stop the submission if any of the validations fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intead of

```
$.trim($("#Options").val()) == ""
```

Try this

```
$('#Options:checked').length == 0
```

Or

```
!$('#Options:checked').length
```

You condition should look like this

```
if( $.trim($("#NameField").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#EmailField").val()) == "" || !$('#Options:checked').length ) {
    console.log("email wrong");
    $("#email_wrong").html("* Please fill in all fields.");
    $("#email_wrong").fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: $('#Options:checked').length is enough.

Comment: @kpsingh... the goal is to show the error (condition must be true)... you probably mean !$('#Options:checked').length with the NOT logical operator to make it less verbose. You reminded me though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!